# Do We have PIPE FUNCTION in HANA

Tags: hana

The  SAP DMO tool uses Pipes for large data chunk migrations , do we have similar Pipe functions in SAP HANA for holding large size data in memeory for doing data migration.

There are some obvious benefits of using Pipe , as the data is stored in memory and intermediate storage stage is not required; hence the data migrations are very quick.

Any pointers to this subject

Comment: Are you asking about other tools for data migrations similar to DMO? Data in SAP HANA is always processed in-memory and access to other DBs is usually done via smart data access (SDA). None of which would require a os level pipe.

Comment: Thanks for reply , actually i am interested in building Data migrations tool that can use Pipe functions . My understanding is that DMO has some limitations , it helps only in transferring data from ECC OR BW databases to SAP HANA